# Animation in android

Tags: android, animation

I want to animate two separate views(overlays) in android. I am doing it using animation api as below:

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(
            getContext(), R.anim.slide_in
        );

    animation.setAnimationListener(new RunnableExecutorAnimationListener(
            null, 
            null, 
            new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    overlay.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
                    invalidate();
                }
            }
        )
    );

    overlay.startAnimation(animation);
```

I want these two view animations to happen as a single unit. Even if I keep the duration of animation same, they appear to move separately. Can this be avoided? and how can we achive this so that animation appears to happen as a single unit?

Comment: http://www.twintechs.com/blog/?p=35

Comment: good one! but I want to do it without adding without using ImageView

Comment: you can use any button or any Imagebutton also

Comment: Is there any way where I don't need to add background resource?and just animate views together?

Comment: I have one linearlayout, one view and statusbar which I want to move together with same speed.The movement is up and down

Comment: What Dr. Nik is suggesting is frame animation, but Ajn appears to be asking about view animation.  (See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html)  I have this question too.  I'd like to say "start animation" and have all of my views animate, with one listener...  I'll answer if I find anything!

Answer (score 0):

Their are few ways of achieving Animation. Use anyone of the following that fits your need 
1. **AnimationDrawable** : This will basically keep swaping your images that you have added to frame, note this should only be used if you have smaller and fewer images or you might face out of memory

```
    AnimationDrawable animation = new AnimationDrawable();
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_1), 1000);
    animation.addFrame(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.image_2), 1000);

    YOUR_IMAGE_VIEW.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);   
    animation.start();

    animation.stop();
```

1. **Using anim xml file**

anim/fadein.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="0.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="1.0" />
```

anim/fadeout.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <alpha xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:duration="1000"
    android:fromAlpha="1.0"
    android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" />
```

In Code:

```
    private Animation animationFadeIn;
    animationFadeIn = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,
            R.anim.fadein);
    VIEW_YOU_WANT_TO_APPLY_ANIMATION.startAnimation(animationFadeIn);
```

do the same for fade_out, and attach that to the same view when your application's logic demands it.

Methods that you mentioned are part of AnimationListener interface use that interface only if you feel you want more control.

Comment: Please do not post the same answer to multiple questions with the exact same content. If the questions are the same, flag or leave a comment explaining that the question is a duplicate. If the questions are different, then please tailor your answer to the question asked.